# Proving error correction performance of a code

Tags: coding-theory

This question is from Introduction to Coding Theory by Ron Ruth (Problem 1.10):

> Show that for every $(n,M,d)$ code $\mathcal{C}$ over $F$ and for
> every decoder $\mathcal{D} : F^n\rightarrow C$ there is a codeword
> $\mathbf{c} \in \mathcal{C}$ and a word $\mathbf{y} \in F^n$ such that
> $d(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{c}) \leq floor\left(\frac{d+1}{2}\right)$ and
> $D(\mathbf{y}) \ne \mathbf{c}$.

I've been trying to prove this but I'm stuck. I tried doing proof by contradiction but I didn't succeed. Could anyone explain and/or give hints on how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $D(y)=c,$ for all codewords $c\in C$ and for all words $y\in F^n$ such that $d(y,c)\leq \lfloor (d_{min}+1)/2 \rfloor.$

The assumption above means that the code can correct all errors with Hamming weight $\lfloor (d_{min}+1)/2 \rfloor,$ which implies that Hamming spheres of radius $\lfloor (d_{min}+1)/2 \rfloor$ around all codewords are disjoint.

If $d_{min}$ is odd this implies that all pairs of codewords are at least $$2\lfloor (d_{min}+1)/2\rfloor= d_{min}+1 $$apart in Hamming distance which gives the contradiction, since by definition of an $(n,M,d_{min})$ code,
$d_{min}$ is the largest $d$ for which $d(c,c')\geq d$ for all $c\neq c'$ in $C.$

If $d_{min}$ is even, the error correction capability is actually $d_{min}/2-1=(d_{min}-2)/2<\lfloor (d_{min}+1)/2\rfloor$ so the contradiction still holds.